# Acces denied for oauth2 request while fetching token

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

In google adwords, ClienLogin method is deprecated. I need to switch over to Oauth2      authentication method

My example code is below,

```
  :method: OAUTH2_JWT
  :user_agent: test
  :developer_token: "*********"
  :oauth2_issuer: "*********@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
  :oauth2_secret: notasecret
  :oauth2_keyfile: '*********-privatekey.p12'
  :client_id: *********.googleusercontent.com
  :oauth2_prn: *********@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  :client_customer_id: *********
```

When i running the request , i am getting error as below

```
  Authorization failed.  Server message: (Signet::AuthorizationError)
  {
    "error" : "access_denied",
    "error_description" : "Requested scopes not allowed:         https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/"
  }
```

Anyone tell me solution to fetch the access token.

Answer (score 0):

An OAuth2 + Google service account means that you have a Google Apps domain (e.g. you use GMail enterprise).

I recommend you to watch the [Adwords API workshop on OAuth2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjaJMagip5s&list=PLKByxjzUC-N_yESo9Ke25eiPC3Gw4bbsL&index=3)

The [OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is also helpful for testing purposes, before you try to use it straight from your app.

Comment: I think Oauth2 with service account are not fully supported by adwords  api at this time. Try using it with [installed application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: @karan I see. Yes it makes sense then.